# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController Delegate Not Working

Tags: ios, delegates, abpeoplepickerview

My goal is to allow the user to import contact details (phone, name and email) from contacts. When I set up an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and set the delegate to self, the delegate methods are not being called. The people picker view is being displayed Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)importFromContacts:(id)sender
{

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *newNavController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    newNavController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:newNavController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    NSLog(@"cancel");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

What am I missing? I would also like to add that the class ABPeoplePicker does not seem to be part of the UIAddressBook framework anymore. It is not in the docs either.

Answer (score 5):

You're setting `delegate`, which describes the object that should handle UINavigationController's delegate methods.

Change

```
newNavController.delegate = self;
```

to

```
newNavController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
```

(As described in the [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController.  It's not out of the ordinary for an object to have multiple delegates, even within the same class.)

Comment: No problem… just don't let it happen again ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this one
**- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person**